# Returning json results at the same page in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, laravel

I have trouble returning my search results as json in same page that I searched,

this is my function for `search page`

```
public function track(Request $request){
    return view('front.track');
}
```

this is `route for it`:

```
Route::get('/track', 'frontend\FrontendController@track')->name('track');
```

and this function to `get results of my search`

```
public function shippingcode(Request $request){
    $rajaongkir = new Rajaongkir\Domestic('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    $shippingcode = $request->input('shippingcode');
    $item = Order::where('shippingcode', $shippingcode)->first();
    $courier = $item->courier;
    $results = $rajaongkir->waybill($shippingcode, $courier);
    return response()->json($results);
  }
```

and this is `route for it`:

```
Route::post('/shippingcode', 'frontend\FrontendController@shippingcode')->name('shippingcode');
```

and finally this is my `search form` in blade:

```
<form class="form-inline text-center" action="{{route('shippingcode')}}" method="post">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <lable>Shipping Code #</lable>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shippingcode" placeholder="93657275025">
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit" type="submit" name="button">Track</button>
</form>
```

## Issue

Issue is except getting results bottom of my form I will redirect to another page and see results as JSON.

any idea?

## UPDATE

I have added jquery to my page in order to get results but still i will redirect to another page:

`JavaScript`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('button[id="submit"]').on('click', function() {
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });


      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('shippingcode') }}',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
            $('div#results').empty();
            $("div#results").html(data);
        }
      });

    });
  });
</script>
```

and added this div bottom of my form `<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="results"></div>`

Comment: nobody have idea? :\

Comment: You need to prevent default post action of the `form` - `$('button[id="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {e.preventDefault();..`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SOLVED

> Note: using `e.preventDefault();` alone would not help at all, however
>   is necessary to have it.

Here is how I done it:

first of all I changed my function to code below:

```
public function shippingcode($code){
    $rajaongkir = new Rajaongkir\Domestic('xxxxxxxxxxxx');
    $shippingcode = $code;
    $item = Order::where('shippingcode', $shippingcode)->first();
    $courier = $item->courier;
    $results = $rajaongkir->waybill($shippingcode, $courier);
    return response()->json($results);
  }
```

and then I changed my `route` from `POST` to `GET` and added my `{code}` into it (look in my function).

```
Route::get('/shippingcode/{code}', 'frontend\FrontendController@shippingcode');
```

Finally I changed my `JavaScript` code to the following code. `here I used e.preventDefault();` but pay attention how I got my button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $.ajaxSetup({
          headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') }
      });
      var shippingcodedd = $("#code").val();
      if(shippingcodedd) {
      $.ajax({
        url: '{{ url('shippingcode') }}/'+encodeURI(shippingcodedd),
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
            $('div#results').empty();
            var summar = data.data.summary;
            $('div#results').append('Data prints here!');
        }
      });
      }else{
        $('div#results').empty();
        $('div#results').append('Sorry there is no info regarding to your tracking code in our system!');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

**PS:** just for completeness here is my `form` HTML code:

```
<form class="form-inline text-center" action="" method="post">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  <lable for="shippingcode">Shipping Code #</lable>
  <input type="text" id="code" class="form-control" name="shippingcode" placeholder="93657275025">
  <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit" name="button">Track</button>
</form>
```

Hope it help others.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default action of your form which is submitting the form via POST method to provided action URL.
Try adding -

```
$('button[id="submit"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Your own login
});
```